# Kendo grid - close addRow and display edit row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have grid, with inline edit function. When I click to Add Record button, new editable row is displays. When i click on edit button in another row, the add row is cenceled and I must click again on edit button.

So, I must click twice on edit button if I befere clicked to Add Record button. It is possible to edit row in one click maybe in Grid `Edit` event ?

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TT.Web.Models.ViewModel.WorkViewModel>()
                      .Name("gridAdd")
                      .Events(events => events.Edit("gridEdit").DataBound("databoundinitAdd").Save("gridAddSaveChanges"))
```

Maybe:

```
function gridEdit(e){

    $(".k-grid-cancel").click(); // remove ADD record ROW (no work)..
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I can think of currently is to define custom buttons with custom "click" event handlers for the "cancel", "update" and "edit" commands. For your convenience I created small example which you can use as baseline to achieve the desired behavior:

- http://dojo.telerik.com/EqOmU/3